# bottom of the background frame is gone

Tags: html, css

I have created a frame for my image but there is a little problem! As you can see in below code the bottom of the frame is gone :/, I don't know why??? can anybody help me please?!

```css
.framed-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url("https://image.ibb.co/kXCWvS/frame.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 18px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img class="framed-image" src="http://placehold.it/1/365f83">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<img>` you are applying the `background-image` to is square, but the background-image source is not. You are using `background-size: cover` to define how the background renders in the space.

From [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) here is what 'cover' does:

> Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If
>   the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped
>   either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

This means that the background-image you are using is filling the width of your img and the bottom part gets cropped off.

To get the frame to distort to fit the square shape you should set the background-size property to:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

This will make its height and width match that of the item it is applied to.

```css
.framed-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url("https://image.ibb.co/kXCWvS/frame.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding: 18px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img class="framed-image" src="http://placehold.it/1/365f83">
```

Answer (score 0):

your background frame image is larger in height than the required image size you are using. you may use background as stretched for every picture or you may change the size of image to fit in the frame.